# Limit the number of tables in RDS ReadReplica (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 100+ tables in Source DB and I need a read-replica with just 10 tables.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Amazon RDS Read Replica is a **complete copy** of the database.

You cannot select which tables to include in the Read Replica.